# Authorization Required on Twitter Stream Api using Guzzle PHP

Tags: oauth, twitter-streaming-api, php-7.1, guzzle

I want to use the Twitter Streaming Api with the filter query. 
And following the GuzzleHttp documentation I'm accessing like this:

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1;

$stack = HandlerStack::create();

$middleware = new Oauth1([
    'consumer_key'    => 'my_key',
    'consumer_secret' => 'my_secret',
    'token'           => 'my_token',
    'token_secret'    => 'my_token_secret'
]);
$stack->push($middleware);

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/',
    'handler' => $stack,
    'auth' => 'oauth'
]);

$client->post('statuses/filter.json', [
    'form_params' => [
        'track' => 'some_word_to_track',
    ],
]);
```

But when executing this code, I'm getting the following exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: 
Client error: 'POST https://stream.twitter.com/statuses/filter.json'
resulted in a '401 Authorization Required' response 
in /Users/.../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:111
```

**Conclusion:**

- Is it because I cannot use GuzzleHttp's Oauth1 Subscriber with
  Twitter streaming API?
- Or is it because I missing something on the
  authentication?